# ios 8.0.1 - download completed but unable to install

Tags: ipad, software-update, ios

I downloaded iOS 8.0.1, tried couple of times - 'Install Now', it asks me to enter passcode, then it asks me to accept 'Terms and Conditions', once accepted it shows message - 'Verifying update...', after some time it shows message:

> **Unable to verify update**
>
> iOS 8.0.1 failed verification because you are no longer connected to
>   the Internet

Though I am connected to Internet :(

I am trying to upgrade it on iPad mini - retina display.

Any clues?

Comment: You should be happy that you weren't able to install it. They really botched that update.

Comment: what if we are trying to delete the new update 8.0.2 and we go settings<then to general< then we go to usage< then manage storage< but the ios 8.0.2 is not showing up to delete it can you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple revoked iOS 8.0.1 last night after issues with iPhone 6 models were revealed.

The installation is failing as the device can't verify the download is correct as iOS 8.0.1 is no longer available.

To delete the download, go to:
Settings app -> General -> Usage -> Manage Storage

Find the iOS 8.0.1 option, select it and tap delete.

Finally, go back to the Software Update screen and it will show iOS 8.0 as up to date.

Comment: Note that the Settings app will retain a badge number of 1. 
This will be resolved when Apple release iOS 8.0.2 soon.

Comment: That did the trick for me

Comment: +1 ... after deleting the 8.0.1 download this way, it finally finds & lets me install 8.0.2

Answer (score 2):

8.0.1 was removed last night from Apple's servers. To fix your issue without having to restore the phone, follow the instructions: [here](http://www.imore.com/ios-801-kill-touch-id-and-cell-service-your-iphone-6-or-iphone-6-plus-heres-how-to-fix):

> Turn off Find my iPhone via Settings > iCloud. Download iOS 8 for
>   iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus. Make sure you're on the latest version of
>   iTunes. Go to About and then Check for Updates or visit iTunes.com.
>   Launch iTunes on your Mac or PC. Connect your iPhone 6 or iPhone 6
>   Plus to iTunes via Lightning to USB cable. Hold down Option (Mac) or
>   Shift (Windows) click on "Check for Update". Choose the iOS 8 firmware
>   file (.ispw) you downloaded in step 2. Let iTunes do its thing. Once
>   you're back up and running, Turn Find my iPhone back on.